# Percona PITR makes oplog slices invalid as per docs

Tags: mongodb, percona, mongodump, mongorestore

I’m looking for a way to backup large mongodb instance like around 5 TB.
Came across the Poihnt-In-Time-Recovery feature in Percona Backup Manager. Went through the docs and understood how it works mostly.

It was mentioned that “once PITR restore is done, the operation changes the timeline of oplog slices. Therefore, all oplog slices made after the restore time stamp and before the last backup become invalid”.

Can someone please provide more information on this? I couldn’t find it on official docs.
https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-backup-mongodb/point-in-time-recovery.html#point-in-time-recovery